# Error in hasGroups: argument "dataset" is missing, with no default in a an app with modules

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building an app with modules and I'm seeing this error when I try to run a histogram or anything. I'm trying to understand what this error means.

```
Warning: Error in hasGroups: argument "dataset" is missing, with no default
```

I've tried to change the `dataset` in the server as a function and as an object, but I didn't work.

Example app

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

importUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    awesomeRadio(
      inputId = ns("choosedata"),
      label = "Choose own data or package datasets",
      choices = list("Own Data" = "own", "Package Datasets" = "pdata"),
      selected = "own",
      inline = TRUE,
      status = "success",
      width = "300px"
    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choosedata == 'pdata'",  ns = ns,
                     selectInput(ns("dataset"), label = "Choose sample dataset", choices = ls("package:datasets"), selected=ls("package:datasets")[[4]])
    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choosedata == 'own'",  ns = ns,
                     fileInput(ns("file1"), "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
                     checkboxInput(ns("header"), "Header", TRUE)
    )
  )
}

importSE <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 dtreact <- reactive({
              
                   
                   if (input$choosedata == "own") {
                     file <- input$file1
                     if (!is.null(file)) {
                       req(input$file1)
                  
                       ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
                       validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
                       mydata <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
                     } else mydata <- NULL
                   } else {
                     mydata <- get(input$dataset, "package:datasets")
                   }
                   
                   mydata
                 })
                 
                 options(shiny.maxRequestSize=800*1024^2) 
                 
    
                 
                 output$contents <- renderTable({
                   dtreact()
                 }, spacing = "xs")
                 
                 return(dtreact)
               }
  )
}


histogramUI <- function(id,var,bins, dataset) {
  tagList(
    fluidRow(column( 4, selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(dataset),selected=var),
                     numericInput(NS(id, "bins"), "bins", value = bins, min = 1)),
             column(8, plotOutput(NS(id, "hist"))))
  )
}


histogramServer <- function(id, dataset) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    req(dataset())
    observeEvent(dataset(), {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "var", choices = names(dataset()))
      
    })
    data <- reactive(dataset[[input$var]])
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(data(), breaks = input$bins, main = input$var)
    }, res = 96)
  })
}


ui <- function(request){fluidPage(

      importUI("import_data"),
      tableOutput("data_head"),
      actionButton("add", "Add Histogram"),
      div(id = "add_here")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  dataset <- importSE("import_data")  

    output$data_head <- renderTable({
      req(dataset())
      head(dataset())
    })
  
  add_id <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    bins <- 10
    histogramServer(paste0("hist_", input$add+add_id()), dataset = dataset)
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = histogramUI(paste0("hist_", input$add+add_id()),input$var,bins))#}
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

Comment: This is nearly 200 lines of code. Can you possibly edit your example so it's minimally reproducible? That out anything that's not directly related to this question or error. That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: I wasn't thinking or was thinking too much, haha. I've tried to reduce it to about 100 lines now with the recent edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for the error is that your `histogramUI()` function has a `dataset=` parameter but you are not passing in the `dataset` value you created. So a change to fix that would be

```
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    bins <- 10
    eleid <- paste0("hist_", input$add + add_id())
    
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", 
           ui = histogramUI(eleid, input$var, bins, dataset = dataset))
    histogramServer(eleid, dataset = dataset)
    
  })
```

You also need to be careful to use `()` to get the value of a creative element. So in your UI change

```
choices = names(dataset)
```

to

```
choices = names(dataset())
```

and in your histogramServer the line

```
data <- reactive( dataset[[input$var]])
```

should be come

```
data <- reactive( dataset()[[input$var]])
```